# Sending an s-expression to another buffer

Tags: buffers, repl, eval, sexp

I'm currently working in Clojure with Arcadia, which is requiring me to use a REPL that doesn't have support with Cider. This has been giving me some trouble given how I usually code, so I'd like to know how I can take a given s-expression and send it to a buffer named `*inferior-lisp*` with a return on it so that it will automatically evaluate. Preferably with a way to also return the printed result back into the file at the end of the line in a comment.

I've looked over the documentation for Emacs and I'm having difficulty getting a handle on exactly how I would do this with an interactive function, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Without knowing about anything that you are talking about, my initial thought would be to use the built-in macro `with-current-buffer`.  To the extent that `*inferior-lisp*` is a running process, then you may wish to provide additional details in your question.

Comment: Yeah, I realize honestly the question is not particularly well-worded. I'll see if I can make it more clear in the morning.

Comment: `C-u <f1> ^comint RET` may give you some relevant hits (`comint` is the library which wraps process interaction for things like `*inferior-lisp*`).